# LWCRefresh Lighting-Record-Edit-Form after Save (new record)

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lightning-record-edit-form that is used for both New records and for editing records.  I have some tabs on the page, one for the Record-Edit-Form and other for related objects.  In order to prevent a user from trying to create the related records before saving the opportunity, I would like to only show those tabs.  I would like to use the record-id from the record-edit-form.  Something like:

```
<lightning-tab label="Products" if:true={selectedOppId}>
```

What I am struggling with is how to set the selectedOppId variable with the recordId of the newly created opportunity from the record-edit-form.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks!!

Fred

Comment: It kinda depends how your components structured, but generally you need to use events.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  What I am struggling it’s is how do I get the ID of the new record?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) section `Returning the Record Id` - it has `onsuccess` handler.

Answer (score 1):

There is no conditional attribute for `lightning-tab`, but you can use conditional template within the `lightning-tabset` to hide tabs conditionally (sample HTML snippet below):

```
<template>
    <lightning-tabset>
        <lightning-tab label="Tab1">
            <!-- Content goes here -->
        </lightning-tab>
        <template if:true={showTab}>
            <lightning-tab label="Tab2">
                <!-- Content goes here -->
            </lightning-tab>
        </template>
    </lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

You can find the newly created record's ID in the edit form's `onsuccess` handler method using `event.detail.id` and toggle the conditional property (`showTab`) within this method.